# Can't bind to 'alt' since it isn't a known property of 'i'

Tags: html, angular, binding

I am very new to angular and I am trying to make the video-icon to have alt text attribute and here's the code:

```
<div class="search-result__indicators">
                    <i *ngFor="let tag of resultTags(result)"
                       [class.audio-icon]="tag == 'Audio'"
                       [class.image-icon]="tag == 'Image'"
                       class="c-glyph" role="presentation"></i>

                    <i *ngFor="let tag of resultTags(result)"
                       [class.video-icon]="tag == 'Video'"
                       class="c-glyph" alt="{{'the article inside has video'}}"></i>
</div>
```

However, it is giving me this error:

> Can't bind to 'alt' since it isn't a known property of 'i'. (""
> [class.video-icon]="tag == 'Video'"
> class="c-glyph" [ERROR ->]alt="{{'the article inside has video'}}">

I have tried to change the `i` to `img`, and the error is gone, but somehow the application is not starting with the `img` changes. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, when you converted from the `<i>` (which is a text formatting tag, similar to `<strong>`, like stated above), did you happen to do so as `<img (your attributes)></img>`?  If so, that is most likely your error in the compilation of the component.  `<img>` is a self closing tag.  Try changing this;

```
  <i
    *ngFor="let tag of resultTags(result)"
    [class.video-icon]="tag == 'Video'"
    class="c-glyph"
    alt="{{ 'the article inside has video' }}"
  ></i>
```

to this;

```
  <img
    *ngFor="let tag of resultTags(result)"
    [class.video-icon]="tag == 'Video'"
    class="c-glyph"
    alt="{{ 'the article inside has video' }}"
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `alt` attribute on `<i>` element. `alt` purpose is to provide text in case image can't be displayed. And `<i>` is a text itself, doesnt make much sense to have `alt` on it.